# Does $L^p(L^1([0,1]))$ make sense?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'm examining several function spaces like $L^p(X,\mu)$ where $X$ is a Banach space.

> Is it possible to take $X = L^1([0,1])$ and then look at $L^p(X)$?

The problem I have is that I don't know what kind of measure $X=L^1([0,1])$ should have, and therefore I'm not sure whether $L^p(L^1([0,1]))$ makes sense.

Comment: I don't think that a reasonable measure exists on $L^1([0,1])$. Note that this space is not locally compact, so it does not admit a Haar measure.

Comment: What's the _definition_ of $L^p(X,\mu)$? (My guess is that $\mu$ is a measure on some set $\Omega$, and the elements of $L^p(X,\mu)$ are maps $f:\Omega\to X$. But that's just a guess. Definitions are sort of important - what's the _definition_?)

Comment: In this case we say $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ and we look at functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$.